# Finding Obsolete Code For SQL Server 2012 Upgrade

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, powershell, sql-server-2012

I'm currently trying to find obsolete or deprecated code on a SQL Server 2008 R2 in stored procedures, views, triggers, etc. I can think of two different approaches: use TSQL and search through the objects in `syscomments` (what is the sys table needed for the `INNER JOIN` needed to determine what database the procs belong to?) or use Powershell (I had a PS script for finding obsolete code, but lost it).

**TSQL:**

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(id)
     , text
FROM syscomments
WHERE text LIKE '%[OBSOLETECODE]%'
```

When it comes to this process, which of these would be more effective for performance, or is there a superior approach?

Comment: I don't understand why you'd think PowerShell is necessary here. All it is going to do is ultimately run T-SQL or SMO code anyway. I would run the upgrade advisor and best practices analyzer, which will catch most stuff, but then you have to worry about silly little things that nothing automated will catch, e.g. [#temp tables now get negative object_id values](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2010/11/09/sql-server-11-denali-using-temp-tables.aspx).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks; that helps a lot!  Usually I use the **NOT NULL**, but I'm troubleshooting for other coders here, so you never know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is the unused index queries: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/01/04/sql-server-2008-unused-index-script-download/ and then there is http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server/69676/ for unused stored procedures -- of course the essential report the MD allways runs 10 minutes before the AGM may appear unused in 11 months.... pays your money and takes your chances....